# How to left align the 2nd line of a text if initial text-align is center

Tags: html, css

I am needing to center align text IF there is only ONE line in the text, but left align the 2nd line if it there is one

I've looked online and could not find a solution.

You would set the normal to:

```
text-align: center
```

and I want the initial text to be centered, but then if it wraps to a 2nd line I want the text to start at the left instead of the center.

Picture of the end result:
[image]

but then if it is just one line, I want it to be centered like the below

[image]

Comment: I don’t think there is any trivial way to achieve that using CSS alone.

Comment: probably this will help:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align-last

Comment: @04FS is right. No way to implement this logic into CSS. Not that hard with JS though

Comment: @TemaniAfif but `text-align-last` is not supported on Safari. Deal breaker if you ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing this (or something similar):

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center; 
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Title</p>
  <div class="text">
    Example-TextExample-TextExample-TextExample-Text<br> Example-Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Just wrap a container around it and center it:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Title</p>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Example-TextExample-TextExample-TextExample-Text<br>Example-Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note that using flexbox for a text conainer is not a good idea (ex: https://jsfiddle.net/26y4nzm9/) .. related question:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/54903158/8620333

Comment: Yes, forgot to wrap it in an actual paragraph (`p`).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `display:table`

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.wrapper h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin:5px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: table;
  margin: auto; /* center the block of text keep the default text-align:left inside*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> adipiscing</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. Mauris luctus laoreet nibh,</div>
</div>
```

Or `inline-block`

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-align: center; /*center the text container*/
}

.wrapper h1 {
  margin:5px;
}

.wrapper>div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:left; /*keep the text left aligned inside*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br> adipiscing</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing. Mauris luctus laoreet nibh,</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Aaron3219 the same happen with your code if we consider the same text ;) https://jsfiddle.net/Lu0dn1et/ ... and this is a logical result of wrapping, so the text is perfectly centred. But if I consider `br` like you are doing I will get the result you expect: https://jsfiddle.net/4km7zhb6/

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment before your comment... didn't think about it enough. I am making an edit right now adressing the issue.

Comment: And I think all answers are valid and just a thing of preference.

Comment: @TemaniAfif This appears to do what I want with a couple of changes to my current setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to say this can't be achieved without CSS and you need to use styling to your Code. Next, there are multiple ways of doing the desired effect. I would go on to explain each one of those.

### 1. text-align-last property:

*Quoting directly from W3Schools:*

The `text-align-last` property specifies how to align the last line of a text.

Notice that the `text-align-last` property sets the alignment for all last lines within the selected element. So, if you have a  with three paragraphs in it, text-align-last will apply to the last line of EACH of the paragraphs. To use `text-align-last` on only the last paragraph in the container, you can use :last child.

**Note**: In Edge/Internet Explorer the `text-align-last` property only works on text that has `"text-align: justify"`.

**Browser Support:**

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```css
div.a {
  text-align: center;
  -moz-text-align-last: right; /* For Firefox prior 58.0 */
  text-align-last: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut.</p>
</div>
```

### 2. Using `span`:

By default, `span` is an inline element but you can set `display: block` to it and then you can text align things differently. Notice the use of `!important` here.

**Code Snippet:**

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
}
span {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is the first line
  <span>Second Line</span>
</p>
```

### 3. Using wrappers:

I don't want to repeat answers already provided. [Aaron3219](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10401043/aaron3219) has already used wrappers to answer this question. This answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953856/8208600).