# Detect if a list has overflown and give it a class, in css

Tags: html, css

I would like to do this in CSS if this is possible with no javascript.

I have a list with x amount of items, it could anything. Here is a picture

[image]

The container is a % of the screen, so as i resize, the ul gets smaller, therefore the list items go on a new line.

What I would like to do is give the ul an text alignment of center if there is 1 line and text align of left if there is 2.

Is this possible with css only?

I cant do media queries as the number of items could be anything.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953837/8620333

Comment: thanks ill have a look

Comment: I've done something similar a few years ago and the solution I found in my case was to simply give the `<li>` a `display: inline-block;` and to make the `<ul>` have `text-align: justify;`.
It worked for me, let me know if it helps in your case too.

Comment: thanks i will give this a try and let you know

Comment: is it a new line or a new row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [this](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/RmowPX)?

```css
body {
  background: #11b5c3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 50px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}


/*
.container {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:75%;
}

.container li {
  background: #fefefe;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}*/

.container {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  /* display:flex; */
  /*justify-content:center;*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 500px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.container li {
  background: #fefefe;
  ;
  margin: 3px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tools</h1>
<ul class="container">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It should be in the middle for only 1 row, then left for more than 1

Comment: Hi, I have re-code it as per your need, I think it's working now. would you please check the above code snippet or view it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/RmowPX)

Answer (score 0):

I am piggy-backing off @Mobarak Ali but I think in this case you want to use grid and not flexbox. If you use flexbox with `flexwrap: wrap;` and `justify-content: center;` the items will always be centered. But the OP wants the items to be centered if they don't wrap but then justify on the left side on each subsequent row. Because grid is used for 2d layouts it can achieve this pretty easily.

Add or delete list items to see the effect. Here is a codepen if you prefer that.
https://codepen.io/zenRyoku/pen/rgWBEp

```css
body {
  background: teal;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 50px;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.container {
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(50px, 1fr) );
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.container li {
  width: 50px;
  background: #fefefe;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Tools</h1>
<ul class="container">
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: note that the items won't get centred but the content inside each grid cell will get centred so not like the OP want (reduce the number of item and you will see)

Comment: Thankyou for this but grid layout is not supported on the latest IE :/