# center text only for short, unwrapped lines?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to center text (`text-align: center`) only for lines of text that are short enough to not wrap, but otherwise align left (`text-align: left`)?

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953837/8620333

Comment: I'm not looking to have the broken text centered. Not even a little bit. It must align with other text on the page. I'm looking to have the short text (if it is short) centered, but longer text, long enough to break, left-aligned with other text on the page. Also, some of the solutions involve modifying specific text. This needs to work generally.

Comment: read carefully the duplicate and the link I provided. Don't simply check the first snippet of the first/accepted answer

Comment: Your ``display:inline-block`` fiddle in the comments of one of those answers is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it using flexbox and `justify-content: center`.

```css
div {
  background-color: #e7e7e7;
  width: 200px;
}
p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Short text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>Now this is more like a long text</p>
</div>
```

You can do it in other ways, as long as you wrap an element with the text that will be centered inside another.

Comment: ``display:inline-block`` as in @temani-afif's [https://jsfiddle.net/Lu0dn1et/](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu0dn1et/) got me there with one column, thanks.