# Why does my HTML tag remove the space before it and why doesn't line break work here?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm making a div that takes up the whole screen. I'm using a flexbox to center the content in the middle of the screen. However, when I try to make it bold using `<b>` tags, it removes the white space right before it, and when I use `<br />` to make text go to the next line, it doesn't work.

To get the space in there, I replaced the space with `&nbsp;`. This works, but why does it remove the space without this? The `<br />` problem still exists.

Here is a link to my code: https://codepen.io/kadhirumasankar/pen/xowLEv

```css
#header-container {
  background-color: #374457;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-container">
  Hi, I&#39;m <b>Name</b><br /> Student at <b>University</b>
</div>
```

I think the problem might have something to do with my flexbox, because apart from that it looks like it should work but isn't.

Comment: never make text container a flexbox container: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333

Comment: This might be an issue with how React is rendering your output. If you do `justify-content: space-between` you can see how the elements are actually split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything withing flex box will be flexed, the best way to handle this is to have a container for your text within a flex box. 
Have a look below.

```css
#header-container{
  background-color: #374457;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header-container">
<div>
  Hi, I&#39;m <b>Name</b><br />
  Student at <b>University</b>
  </div>
</div>
```