# How to use 'word-break: break-word' with link inside of text?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a solution to use `word-break: break-word` for a text which contains another element like a `<a>` that works with IE11 and Edge too.

Currently my example looks like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.item {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    Text start and
    <a href="/" class="item">
      a long link that should wrap around
      </a> another part of the text
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My expected outcome would be that the text breaks like this:

[image]

This works fine with `display: contents;` on the item, but unfortunately, this is **not supported by IE11 and Edge**.

I couldn't find any alternatives that work in IE11 and Edge yet, are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: must using "display: flex;" ?

Comment: @dooooooofai I'm fine with any solution

Comment: simply remove flex .. never make a text container a flexbox container (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333)

Comment: yes, if you remove the flex the problem solved wwww

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the little hint I needed :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  Text start and <a href="/" class="item">a long link that should wrap around</a> another part of the text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  word-break: break-word;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/6kp3rmb8/)**