# Vertically center text containing inline elements in flex layouts while preserving whitespace

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking to vertically align text in a list item. I'm using `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;`. But my code contains a `strong` tag, which gets interpreted as a separate flex item, and so the spaces on either side get collapsed.

I could hack it with `&nbsp;`, but is there a *proper* way to get my text, with inline elements, to vertically align center?

- I know I could wrap the text in a `<p>`. I'm trying to avoid that.
- My text might be long enough to wrap, so `line-height` isn't an option.
- Once [display: contents;](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) becomes widely supported, that would be my go-to solution here.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8em;/* just for example */
  border: 2px solid red;/* just for example */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this text is vertically centered!</li>
  <li>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `I know I could wrap the text in a <p>. I'm trying to avoid that.` --> you should do this and never ever make text container a flexbox container, what you have is nothing compared to what you will have if you will have more lines. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333

Answer (score 0):

The only efficient solution to your problem is to remove the text from the *flex formatting context*. You can do this by wrapping the text in another element, making that element the flex item. Now your text is back in a standard *block formatting context*, and the collapsing spaces are no longer a problem.

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8em;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this text is vertically centered!</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also, note that all children of a flex container are block-level elements, regardless of what you specify. So the idea that you're dealing with inline-level elements is incorrect. There are no inline-level elements in a flex container.

> [**§ 4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> The `display` value of a flex item is blockified. If the specified
>   `display` of an in-flow child of an element generating a flex
>   container is an inline-level value, it computes to its block-level
>   equivalent.

More details:

- [How to vertically align text inside a flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25311541/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider CSS grid and fake the borders. You will visually have the expected result:

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
}
ul {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:8em;
  grid-gap:2px;
  align-items:center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) center/100% 2px no-repeat;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this <br>text is vertically centered!</li>
  <li>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</li>
</ul>
```

For more items you can adjust the background:

```css
li {
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
}
ul {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:8em;
  grid-gap:2px;
  align-items:center;
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(transparent 0 8em,red 8em calc(8em + 2px));
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this <br>text is vertically centered!</li>
  <li>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</li>
  <li>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this <br>text is vertically centered!</li>
  <li>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</li>
  <li>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this <br>text is vertically centered!<br>text is vertically centered!</li>
  <li>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

This should fix the problem!

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 8em;/* just for example */
  border: 2px solid red;/* just for example */
}
span {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>It is <strong>Very important</strong> that this text is vertically centered!</span></li>
  <li><span>Also <strong>Very important</strong> that there are spaces in the text.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: He talks about not wanting to wrap the whole thing

Answer (score -3):

In case like this I would suggest using `display: contents` with fallback with `@supports()` using either margin, or pseudo elements with contents of 1 space.