# Making floating box 100% of container box

Tags: html, css

I have a box set to `float:right;` inside a container box. This container box will also have other content.

I am trying to vertically center the text inside the inner box. For that I use `display:flex;` with `align-items: center;`.

As a final step I would now like the height to always fill the container box. So that the vertically centered text inside this inner box is always vertically centered inside the container box.

- The height of the container box adjusts to it's content, so I cannot set a specific height on the boxes in css.
- It also does not help with a `height:100%;` on the inner box.

How can I make this inner box always fill its container box 100% vertically?

Here is an example code snippet: Both inner box and container box will always retain a minimum height of 100 px, but I have added so much text that the container box expands to more than 100 px. It is clear that the inner box does not adjust it's height to this.

```css
#container {
  background-color:#ddd;
  min-height: 100px;
}

#centeredcontent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee; 
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="centeredcontent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
  
  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need float here:

```css
#container {
  background-color:#ddd;
  min-height: 100px;
  display:grid; /* grid container */
  grid-template-columns:auto 30%; /* 2 columns */
  grid-auto-flow:dense; /* this will make sure the text fill the first column */
}

#centeredcontent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee; 
  grid-column: 2; /* your float element on the second column */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="centeredcontent"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></div>
  
  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 </div>
```

A flexbox configuration can also do it:

```css
#container {
  background-color:#ddd;
  min-height: 100px;
  display:flex;
}

#centeredcontent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #eee; 
  width:30%;
  flex-shrink:0;
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="centeredcontent"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></div>
  
  
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
 </div>
```

<sub>PS: I am adding an extra wrapper for your text because you should [never make a text container a flexbox container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903923/8620333)</sub>